# how to understand the each column of output of last

Tags: linux, last

I was using the command `last` to find out what or who reboot our server but got confused with the output. I've looked the documentation and man page of last https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html but can not find any detailed description of what each column means. Can someone help to describe what each column means?
Below is an example of the output of the last:

```
wtmp begins Mon Apr 25 17:46:05 2022
root@robot:~# last -i
root     pts/3        10.65.111.36     Tue Aug  2 12:48   still logged in
root     pts/3        10.65.146.31     Mon Aug  1 11:00 - 11:23  (00:22)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Jul 29 18:55   still running
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Jul 29 16:54 - 18:54  (01:59)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Tue Jul 26 18:45 - 16:53 (2+22:08)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Tue Jul 26 16:50 - 18:44  (01:53)
root     pts/2        10.65.153.180    Mon Jul 25 17:20 - 20:46  (03:25)
root     pts/1        10.65.153.180    Mon Jul 25 15:13 - 18:26  (03:12)
root     pts/0        10.65.153.180    Mon Jul 25 11:12 - 17:25  (06:12)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sun Jul 24 03:23 - 16:49 (2+13:25)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings are:

1. username/action
2. which terminal/action
3. from where (0.0.0.0 mean internal command)
4. timestamp start of session
5. (column before last) end of session
6. length of session/action

The last two columns can be replaced with `still logged in` if user is still logged in to the system.

You can check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/last-command) for more info.